# How do I execute a piece of code or a Python script on an RPi using another Python script running on a PC on the same network?

Tags: python, networking, ssh, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

So basically, a script running on my PC recognizes the number of cars in a video and every time it exceeds a certain threshold, it should send a signal to my RPi that turns on an LED and turns it off after 5 seconds. This is just a simple command that runs not more than 2 times. I tried using sockets to send data but I wasn't able to get it to work. Is there any easy way to just run a script on a network?

Comment: You should consider using ssh between your RPi and PC, after that, it shouldn't be difficult...

Comment: Thanks! I tried this module called spur. It works really well now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use GPIO Zero's remote GPIO feature. Install gpiozero and pigpio on your PC, set an environment variable to use PIGPIO and the Pi's IP address, create an LED object (on the remote pin) and

On the Pi:

1. Enable remote GPIO in Raspberry Pi Configuration
2. Enable pigpiod on boot, and start it now

   ```
   sudo systemctl enable pigpiod
   sudo systemctl start pigpiod
   ```

On the PC:

1. Install gpiozero and pigpio with pip:

   ```
   sudo pip install gpiozero pigpio
   ```
2. Set an environment variable to use pigpio for pins (using the Pi's IP address):

   ```
   GPIOZERO_PIN_FACTORY=pigpio
   PIGPIO_ADDR=192.168.1.5
   ```
3. Write some test code:

   ```
   from gpiozero import LED

   led = LED(17)

   while True:
       input("Press Enter to turn the LED on")
       led.on()
       input("Press Enter to turn the LED off")
       led.off()
   ```
4. Implement the LED code into your existing project on your PC

See the gpiozero docs for more info:

https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/remote_gpio.html

Comment: Thank you so much! This is EXACTLY what I was looking for!